# cannot access to this of component in subscribe function

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying navigate to new page when get answer from server:

```
import {Component} from '../../node_modules/angular2/core';
import {Router} from "../../node_modules/angular2/router";
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '../../node_modules/angular2/http'

@Component({
    selector: 'test-page',
    templateUrl:'src/login/test.html',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})


export class TestPage {
    constructor(private _router:Router,
                private _http:Http) {
    }

    Test(username, password) {
        let body = 'test';
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        this._http.post('/api/test', 'test', {headers: headers})
        .subscribe(
                response => {
                    this._router.navigateByUrl('Home'); //'this' is not a component
                },
                error => {
                   console.log(error)
                }
       );
     }
}
```

But by some reason 'this' is not a pointer to component but it's a subscribe.
Does someone know the reason of issue?

Comment: Could you also add the code around? I mean the complete function where the code is located. Thanks!

Comment: What was the **exact** error message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should cache the variable this before calling the http post, because inside the subscriber this refer to the subscriber itself.

```
let headers = new Headers();
var self = this;
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
this.http.post('/api/test', 'test', {headers: headers})
       .subscribe(
                response => {
                    self._router.navigate(link); 
                },
                error => {
                   console.log(error)
                }
       )
```

Comment: That's redundant if you use `=>` https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: the reason was in self. Thanks a lot

Comment: Agreed with @Günter, with arrow functions, the `this` keyword should be the component instance ifself (because of lexical this). There is something strange here. I used this a lot ;-)

Comment: Quite unlikely that this is the solution.

Comment: I added (respone=>{...}).bind(this)

Comment: I have the same error - looks like after transpilation arrow function gets replaced with `function`

Answer (score 0):

`Router.navigate` doesn't take a components class instance as a parameter

```
this._router.navigate(link);
```

Is invalid.

It requires an array of route names

```
this._router.navigate(['MyRoute']);
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html

Comment: I cannot take this._router at all

Comment: Hard to tell because your question doesn't contain enough code. In your constructor you need `constructor(private _router:Router) {}`.

Comment: Try adding `console.debug(this._router);` to your constructor to check if an instance is actually passed in. You can't inject `Router` in components that don't have routes. Instead inject `Router` to a global service and inject this service to your component.