# cannot get 'this' of component inside subscribe function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angular, typescript, scope

My question is quite similar to these, but i did not solve my problem;

[cannot access to this of component in subscribe function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688955/cannot-access-to-this-of-component-in-subscribe-function)

['this' scope in typescript callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362178/this-scope-in-typescript-callback-function)

[Cannot Access Component Variables in Subscribe when using chrome inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148701/cannot-access-component-variables-in-subscribe-when-using-chrome-inspector)

[unable to get component variables inside a RxJS subscribe() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647449/unable-to-get-component-variables-inside-a-rxjs-subscribe-function?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Here is my typescript component class:

```
export class Test{
     x: string;
}

export class TestComponent implements OnInit{
     test: Test;

     constructor(private testService: TestService){}

     ngOnInit(){
          this.testService.getTest()
               .subscribe((res) => { this.test = res.test;}, ...);
          console.log(this.text.x) //it becomes undefined
     }
}
```

I am using gulp-typescript, and outputs are like these;

```
//when targeting es6

let testComponent = class TestComponent ... {
     constructor(testService){
          this.testService = testService;
     }

     ngOnInit(){
          this.testService.getTest()
               .subscribe((res) => {this.test = res.test;}, ...);
          console.log(this.text.x)
     }
}

//when targeting es5

var TestComponent = (function(){
     function TestComponent(testService){
         this.testService = testService;
     }

     TestComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function(){
          var _this = this;
          this.testService.getTest()
               .subscribe(function (res) { _this.test = res.test }, ...);
          console.log(this.text.x)
     }
}())
```

When I want to try to reach 'this.test.x' I get the following error from browser with both outputs;

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

When I log the `this.test`, it is `undefined`. My TestService is injected properly, request come to my api and `res.test` includes what i need but i cannot use with `this.test` because it is always undefined. I do not know where I am doing wrong. Is there anyone else who can help  me? Finally, I want to ask that, which one should I target when considering browser compatibility etc., es5 or es6?

Comment: What is  `'whateverItIs'`. I don't see that in your code you have posted? Expand the constructor and put a `console.log(testService)` to be sure the service is being passed/injected into the constructor.

Comment: It is just any property of my Test class, I wrote 'whateverItIs' insted of property name. TestService is injected properly, my api gets the request.

Comment: Can you please include some of the code from your test class. Thanks. I just want to see what the real property name is so I can see which object is `undefined`.

Comment: I updated my question @Martin

Comment: Great. Where in the code are you trying to access `this.test.x`? I am not seeing that.

Comment: Let's say in ngOnInit, I am calling `console.log(this.test.x)`, and I am getting error @Martin

Comment: Ok. That would make sense to me. I would expect an error is you called console.log(this.test.x) on ngOnInit. From the code you provided this.test will not be populated until at least the next "turn" of the VM. Though you would be able to call it within the subscribe callback of you are receiving the expected data. This would be the expected behavior. The console.log() is being called BEFORE your subscribe callback. You need to move to the callback.

Comment: I was going to turn this comment into an answer, but it looks like Katana314 beat me too it. Please mark that one as the correct answer. This is a gotcha when moving from synchronous to async programming. Now that it has bitten you, once you understand it you will be immune.

Comment: One final thing, for browser target ES5. ES6 isn't supported on most mobile browsers yet (as of now) and only up to date desktop browsers will support ES6. Finnaly, the ES6 implementations in these browsers have not been optimized as well as the ES5 implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `console.log` statement inside of the arrow function.

```
ngOnInit(){
          this.testService.getTest()
               .subscribe((res) => {
                 this.test = res.test;
                 console.log(this.text.x)
          }, ...);

     }
```

If you had other things you wanted to do with `this.test`, then you're going to have to move those inside too (or, add another function and call that from inside the callback). Basically, if you have a service that returns an `Observable`, that means the callback will not run in the same "frame" that you called the function. In your original code this was the order of operations:

1. getTest is called, an AJAX operation is started
2. console.log called, prints undefined.
3. User gets a second of UI time with not much happening as the request communicates with the server
4. Request finishes, `subscribe(() =>` callback is called. `this.test` is set.

Comment: Here is a link to a deeper explanation of Asynchronous programming. This isn't specific to Angular2 or TypeScript http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/event-based-programming-what-async-has-over-sync--net-30027

Comment: What if I want to use `this.test.x` inside a `[formGroup]`? When I call it inside subscribe, I get error, or should I use template driven form instead of ReactiveForms? @Katana314 @Martin

Comment: You may want to simply wrap your form with an `*ngIf="test"`. This way the form and the reference to `test.x` within the form wont be called until your data has returned. Another option is to use the `async` pipe. Or a combination of the two.

Answer (score 2):

"_this.componentProperty" works for me instead of "this.componentProperty" when inside a "subscribe()" rxjs call.

Comment: Works, but it's marked as an error in the editor because _this is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace your function TestComponent.prototype.ngOnInit for an Arrow function, so "this" would be accesible from your subscribe call.