# Setting a variable in the component from an observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am trying to bind a variable in a component to the content from an observable in a subscribe() function with an anonymous function:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.strSub = this._store.select(selectStr).subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
    //this.strSub = this._store.select(selectStr).subscribe((data) => {this.str = data});
}
```

The uncommented line runs fine while the commented line throws an error on compilation `Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.`.

In other words, this assignment `this.str = data` somehow breaks the program. I suspect this may be due to `data` being null at some point during run-time, and I added a check with `if (data) {...}` but it still failed to compile.

I have seen people bind variables in components this way (so it should be a valid way to approach this problem), but don't understand why this isn't allowed here.

Below is the full code for this example which consists of a single component.ts with a selectors.ts, reducer.ts and actions.ts:

Component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(private _store: Store) {}
    strSub: Subscription;
    str: string;
    numChanged: number;
    observable: Observable<string>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.strSub = this._store.select(selectStr).subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
    //this.strSub = this._store.select(selectStr).subscribe((data) => {this.str = data});
    // this.observable = this._store.select(selectStr)
}
}
```

Selectors.ts

```
export const myTopLevelSelector = createFeatureSelector<fromReducer.State>(fromReducer.featureKey);

export const selectStr = createSelector(myTopLevelSelector, (state) => {state.str});
```

Reducer.ts

```
export const featureKey = 'myFeatureKey';

export interface State {
    str: string,
    numChanged: number
}

export const initialState: State = {
    str: "initialState",
    numChanged: 0
}

const myReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(myAction1, (state, action) => ({
        ...state,
        str: action.str,
        numChanged: state.numChanged + 1
    }))
)    

export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
    return myReducer(state, action);
}
```

Actions.ts

```
export const myAction1 = createAction('ACTION1', props<{str: string, numChanged: number}>());

export const myActionSuccess = createAction('ACTIONSUCCESS');
```

The HTML file is an unremarkable one-liner:
`<p>{{this.str}}</p>`

I looked at this thread (and the links it contains): [cannot get 'this' of component inside subscribe function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118301/cannot-get-this-of-component-inside-subscribe-function), and the problem is somewhat similar in format, but a fundamental difference is that I'm not trying to log; I'm trying to assign, and the assignment doesn't work while the logging works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem that you are having is in your selector.

Remove the brackets from the arrow funtion if you have them you will need to add the `return` into it.

Without brackets

```
export const selectStr = createSelector(myTopLevelSelector, (state) => state.str);
```

With brackets

```
export const selectStr = createSelector(myTopLevelSelector, (state) => { return state.str })
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Amazing. It worked like a charm. Thank you. Sometimes I wonder how will I ever figure that out myself. I guess it's about treading more roads on this journey.